# Unable to make a ajax call in my custom wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am writing a plugin in wordpress. In between I am trying to make a ajax call, but I am not able to post data to the php file I am looking for. SO far I have googled a lot and find some some code snippets, but nothing seems to be working the way I am looking for.

Here is the code snippet I am currently implementing.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#status').change(function(){
            $.post( "index.php", { id: "1", status: "2" } );
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am looking to redirect to my plugins index.php file to make the rest of the database operations. But its redirecting me to the wp-admin/index.php page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Put the ajax operation in your main plugin file

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );

function my_action_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $id = intval( $_POST['id'] );
    $status = $_POST['status'];

    echo 'whatever';

    die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

And call your ajax function like this:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
      var data = {
        'action': 'my_action',
        'id'    : '1',
        'status': '2'
      };
      // We can also pass the url value separately from ajaxurl for front end AJAX implementations
      jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Not seems to be working! even the alert is getting fired during the call!

Comment: In which file did u add the `PHP` block?

Comment: In addition throwing me an error in the console panel:
ReferenceError: ajax_url is not defined

Comment: I added the PHP block in my plugin file

Comment: Check the updated answer. It's working and make sure you are getting response code '200' when you fire ajax query.

Comment: Now where should I define the function: my_action(), the same file where I already have the above snippet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66638/discussion-between-mangesh-parte-and-dreamer).